# Upgrading Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I have been using the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers for Juno (4.2 SR1) that I had downloaded from the eclipse site as the custom binary. With the [slowness that haunts Juno](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272), this is almost unusable. The eclipse team is making fixes which they are advertising as being made available on their milestone builds. Can someone please guide me as to:

1. Whether one can upgrade the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers to pick up relevant changes from the milestones update site?
2. If yes, how are conflicts resolved?

I tried adding an [update site for Juno milestones](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2-M-builds) and tried an upgrade for the Eclipse platform as mentioned [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272#c57)
After calculating dependencies, it gave details as to why it can't proceed which I wasn't able to decipher.

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "Eclipse Platform" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Platform 4.2.2.M20121121-1200 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 4.2.2.M20121121-1200)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.2.0.v20120829-072800 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.2.0.v20120829-072800)
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.2.0.v20120912-144258 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.2.0.v20120912-144258)
    Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.2.0.v20120606-135340 (org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.2.0.v20120606-135340)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.5.1.20120917-1257]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.doc.user [4.2.0.v20120829-072800]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20121115-222257-9LF7DHVKG-F1itrD-OMdQj0FBElP-MWn4gn9s_ (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20121115-222257-9LF7DHVKG-F1itrD-OMdQj0FBElP-MWn4gn9s_)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.doc.user [4.2.0.v20120912-144258]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.2.2.M20121121-1200 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 4.2.2.M20121121-1200)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.2.1.v20121115-222257-9LF7DHVKG-F1itrD-OMdQj0FBElP-MWn4gn9s_]
```

Can someone please help me out? I thought of hitting the eclipse forums as well, but thought might get a quicker response out here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272,

1. Help>Install New Software
2. use the site: [junoSR1Patch](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/junoSR1Patch-tmp)
3. select Eclipse UI Juno SR1 Optimizations, install, and restart

All fixes are also in Kepler builds, however the next Kepler milestone isn't for a few more weeks yet. Your best bet is to install the official patch candidate, which works for all EPP packages as well as Eclipse "classic" SDK

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time on this. Just download a new [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: this doesn't solve the performance problem as in SR1 exists the same issue

Comment: Note you can click under Developer Builds to get the latest milestone, as of this comment its Kepler (4.3) M5.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Kepler M3 Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers at [this download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/kepler/m3).